# Clicker counter Save/Load resetting count

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm pretty damn new to C# and have had some ups and downs with it.

I'm currently stuck, after many hours of trial and error, I finally managed to get a save/load implemented. However, when the file loads up and I try to continue, the count resets to 0 and I'm unsure how to approach this.
This is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp11 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        int count = 0;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
                count++;
                label1.Text = count.ToString();
            } else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
                count--;
                label1.Text = count.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
            Properties.Settings.Default.label = label1.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            label1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.label;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign `count` when you reload the form. You just assign the setting to `label1.Text`, so it shows up in the UI, but when you press the button, it goes back to 1 (`count` was 0 because that's what you initialize it to). Change the form load event to something like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.label;
        int.TryParse(label1.Text, out count);
    }
```

`int.TryParse` will look at what's in `label1.Text` (which we assigned from the setting) and if it's a valid `int`, assign it to the `count` field.

Comment: For those not familiar with winforms, no explicit Load is needed because this is saved in settings that will auto load. I would probably save count to settings rather than the text field, but I'm keeping this in vein with what OP asked, not knowing if there's more they're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable `int count = 0` which you increment and decrease based on user clicks. That's perfectly fine. Now when you try to save *and retrieve* the value of that variable into/from application settings, you don't actually do that, instead you are saving the text of the label *and then setting its text again on load without assigning your `count` variable*.

What you need to do is:

- In the application settings, make sure that the type of your `label` setting is `int` and not `string`.
- (optional) better change the name of that settings to `Count` or something similar.
- When closing the form, you need to save the value of your local variable `count`.
- When the form loads, you retrieve the value from the settings (either `label` or `Count`), and assign it to the the local variable.

Here's an illustration example:

```
int count = 0;

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        count--;
    }
    label1.Text = count.ToString();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The name of the setting here is `Count`.
    // You can change it to something else if you want.
    count = Properties.Settings.Default.Count;
    label1.Text = count.ToString();
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Count = count;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested however it appears to still reset the count when the button is pressed after the program has been reloaded

Comment: @procoderin1956 My mistake, I didn't test the code, and I missed something when typing it. If you follow the steps in my answer, you should be able to find the mistake I made by yourself :) The code is fixed now anyway.